# Página Ionic 4 não carrega atualização de listagem de registros após alguma alteração

Tags: ionic

Seguinte pessoal, eu tenho dois componentes no Ionic, um que lista os usuários e outro que mostra os detalhes para modificação. Toda a navegação no meu app é feita por meio de rotas. Ocorre que após eu adicionar um novo registro, ou alterar um existente, ou até mesmo excluir algum registro, ao ser direcionado novamente para a página de listagem de usuários utilizando o `this.router.navigate(['/list']);`, não está ocorrendo atualização automática das informações na página /list, somente aparece o novo registro por meio de inclusão, modificação ou remoção se eu atualizar a página /list com F5 (testes realizados no navegador do notebook).

Tem como resolver isso no ionic 4? Gostaria que quando a rota fosse direcionada novamente a página de listagem usando o `this.router.navigate(['/list']);` ou outro método, já constasse os dados atualizados na /list, lembrando que utilizo uma página para listagem /list e outra página de detalhes do registro. /detail-users.

Comment: Você poderia dar mais informações colega? Somos advinhos agora? -1

Comment: Hehehe foi mal @MauryDeveloper, vou reformular a pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deu certo aqui pessoal.

Foi só usar o evento ionViewWillEnter.

O evento ionViewWillEnter é disparado ao entrar em uma página antes de se tornar a ativa . Use-o para tarefas que você deseja fazer toda vez que entrar na visualização (definindo ouvintes de eventos, atualizando uma tabela, etc.).

Ficou assim meu código que chama o get dos usuários na página:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    //this.getUsers(); antes eu tava chamando o método aqui
  }

  async ionViewWillEnter() { //Foi só eu trocar o nome do método para ionViewWillEnter.
    await this.api.getUser()
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.users = res;
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```